# How to specify "today's date" in context for Watson Conversation Service

Tags: watson-conversation

From the Watson Conversation service documentation (http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/advanced_overview.shtml), it says context variable can be used to save user input.  Is there a way to predefine a variable inside context, such as today's date?

For example, I have a dialog set up to answer questions about the schedule of an event that span for 3 days (say Sept 12, 13, 14).  If someone asks about "today"'s special performance and today is Sept 12, it will give the information about Sept 12, not the other days.

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on in the system entities tab a system entity named `sys-date` and the user writes "today" in his text input, the Watson will reply with recognized `sys-date` entity that will hold the today's date (will recognized "today" as `sys-date` entity). You can then used this recognized `sys-date` entity in the dialog flow and condition dialog nodes on its value (e.g. to solve your particular use-case).